# Django gallery with jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

I want to create image gallery. I have only miniatur without bigImage 
I don't know what i do wrong.

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{{ product.name }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ImageGallery img').click(function () {
            var bigImagePath = '{{image.image.url}}' +  $(this).attr('alt');
            $('#bigImage').attr('src', bigImagePath);
        })

    })
</script>

<div id="ImageGallery">
    {% for image in images %}
        <img src="{{image.image_url}}" alt="test" style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer;">

    <div>
        <img id="bigImage" alt="">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

ImageGallery is show on site without BigImage. I think my mistake is on jq

Comment: Did my answer helped you someway? If so, mark it as accepted. That's a good practice in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is not in jQuery but about what your context is in order to render this html.

Since `ImageGallery` is rendered correctly (as you say), this is because `{{ image }}` is taken from the `for` loop. But on the line: `var bigImagePath = '{{image.image.url}}' +  $(this).attr('alt');` does the `{{ image.image.url }}` variable exists? Note that its outside of the `for` loop.